# DXE7: "type A = type B" and var x (of type A):= A.create leads to E2010 incompatible type compile error. Why?

Tags: class, delphi, types, wsdl, redeclaration

**A. Short summary of the problem:**

```
type
  A = class(TObject)
  end;

  B = type A;
```

The compiler error `E2010 incompatible types: 'B' and 'A'` is shown, when you instantiate a variable of class B in the following style:

```
var
  TheB: B;
begin
     TheB:= B.Create;
     ..
```

I can avoid that problem by removing the second "type", so the declaration is the standard one:

```
type
  A = class(TObject)
  end;

  B = A;
```

But in my opinion, the error should not come, even WITH the second "type", because A is not directly used (The second "type" tells the compiler to see both classes as individuals, see http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Declaring_Types for details). Can someone explain, because of what reason the error ignores my opinion? (o;

**B. Complete history and more complex details:**

First of all: The error:

`[dcc32 Fehler] gboDHL.pas(165): E2010 Inkompatible Typen: 'Origin' und 'CountryType'`
(which means "incompatible types" in english),

occurs in the following line of code:

```
AShipmentOrder.Shipment.Shipper.Address.Origin:= DHL_geschaeftskundenversand_api_2.Origin.Create;
```

Now here is the background:

I try to communicate with the "new" DHL Geschäftskundenversand API v2.2 which still uses SOAP to create a shipment order. `DHL_geschaeftskundenversand_api_2` is the completely generated unit from the integrated delphi xe7 WSDL generator for that service.
`AShipmentOrder` is the instance which represents the top level xml node of the request.

The class "Origin" is implemented/generated this way:

```
type    
  CountryType = class(TRemotable)
  private
    Fcountry: country2;
    Fcountry_Specified: boolean;
    FcountryISOCode: countryISOType;
    Fstate: state;
    Fstate_Specified: boolean;
    Fcountry_: country;
    Fcountry__Specified: boolean;
    FcountryISOCode_: countryISOType;
    Fstate_: state2;
    Fstate__Specified: boolean;
    procedure Setcountry(Index: Integer; const Acountry2: country2);
    function  country_Specified(Index: Integer): boolean;
    procedure Setstate(Index: Integer; const Astate: state);
    function  state_Specified(Index: Integer): boolean;
    procedure Setcountry_(Index: Integer; const Acountry: country);
    function  country__Specified(Index: Integer): boolean;
    procedure Setstate_(Index: Integer; const Astate2: state2);
    function  state__Specified(Index: Integer): boolean;
  published
    property country:         country2        Index (IS_OPTN) read Fcountry write Setcountry stored country_Specified;
    property countryISOCode:  countryISOType  read FcountryISOCode write FcountryISOCode;
    property state:           state           Index (IS_OPTN) read Fstate write Setstate stored state_Specified;
    property country_:        country         Index (IS_OPTN) read Fcountry_ write Setcountry_ stored country__Specified;
    property countryISOCode_: countryISOType  read FcountryISOCode_ write FcountryISOCode_;
    property state_:          state2          Index (IS_OPTN) read Fstate_ write Setstate_ stored state__Specified;
  end;

  Origin          =  type CountryType;      { "http://dhl.de/webservice/cisbase"[GblElm] }
```

The "property" Origin of `AShipmentOrder.Shipment.Shipper.Address` is implemented/generated this way:

```
type
 NativeAddressType = class(TRemotable)
 ...
 published
 ...
   property Origin: Origin  Index (IS_OPTN or IS_REF) read FOrigin write SetOrigin stored Origin_Specified;
 ...
 end;
```

If it is unclear, let me say, that ´AShipmentOrder.Shipment.Shipper.Address´ is of class `NativeAddressType`

I'm using Delphi XE7 on Windows 10, 64bit, compiling to 32bit.

The delphi WSDL generator has different problems, which I had to manage before, and it is really not "nice" that in the output the property names are identical to the class names, but that is not changeable, it seems.
The class "Origin" is not the only class in that generated unit which is named as the property it belongs to, but the error only occurs, when such a class is implemented as

```
type
 A = type B
```

I tried to find a description of that special declaration variant, but that is quite hard, because the keywords are too often used.

On http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/RTL.asp?Name=Type I found the following explanation:

`1.type Name = Existing type  
Refers to an existing type, such as string by a new Name. 
 
2.type Name = type Existing type  
This has the same effect as above, but ensures that at run time, variables of this type are identified by their new type name, rather than the existing type name.`

If I understand that correctly, that means that in my example the class `Origin` is not identified anymore as `CountryType`, but as `Origin`. That should be fine, because the property `Origin` is declared as to be of class `Origin`.

While going on to try to understand that problem, I manually renamed The class "Origin" in the generated unit to OriginType (delphi used that postfix "Type" with several other classes in that unit, not clear, why it has not used it with the Origin-Type). After that, I can exclude a name-conflict, because now the error is

`[dcc32 Fehler] gboDHL.pas(165): E2010 Inkompatible Typen: 'OriginType' und 'CountryType'`

There seems to be no reason because of what that error occurs.

After some hours without some ideas I found this Embarcadero WIKI entry: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Declaring_Types

After reading and thinking about that, I understood, that the "type" in `A = type B` is not necessary in that case, because there is no need to handle class A in another way than class B, so I removed that manually in the generated unit and now, it works fine.

I also understand, that a special option in the generator was checked to prevent "name conflicts". If this option is not checked, this problem also should be solved (but maybe some others come around (o; ).

Maybe this helps someone to spent more time outside than with a problem like that (o;

But in the end, I do not understand what was the problem here, because all properties were of type "Origin" and later of "OriginType", also this type was created with `Origin.Create` and later with `OriginType.Create`. So the "CountryType" was never used, except for the class declaration of "Origin" / "OriginType". In my opinion this should not lead to that problem, but it does.

Can somebody explain that?

Thank you in advance

Kai

Comment: In the `NativeAddressType` declaration, Ctrl+Click on `Origin`. The IDE will take you to the declaration of that type. Now Ctrl+Click on `DHL_geschaeftskundenversand_api_2.Origin` on the line where you call `Create`. Does the IDE take you to the same place as before?

Comment: If it does not take you to the same place that means the types are not identical. They need to be identical to avoid the error shown.

Comment: Please read carefully. In the big code box, is the declaration of CountryType and Origin. As shown there, Origin is declared as `type CountryType;` This, of course is also the place, where the IDE takes me when I do Ctrl+click on the classname Origin. So both classes are the same, except for the name. As the "type" makes them handled independedly by the compiler, the question is, why it comes to a incompatibility with CountryType, when CountryType is not used anywhere directly, only "Origin" is used. See details in the question above.

Comment: Maybe the question was quite confusing, because I asked a question to myself inside of the "history". I thought that would help to better come into the problem and asked the "real" question in the end, but maybe I was wrong. I now edited the question and replaced the sentence "But because of what, this error occurs" by "There seems to be no reason because of what that error occurs". Also I added a short summary of the problem, so it should be more clearer, what the real question is. Sorry, if it leaded to confusion. Please overthink the downvote. regards Kai

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting: `E2010 Incompatible types: 'Tb' and 'Ta'`, which might seems odd:

```
type
  Ta = class
  end;
  Tb = type Ta;
var
  b: Tb;
begin
  b := Tb.Create;  // E2010 Incompatible types: 'Tb' and 'Ta' 
end.
```

`Ta` and `Tb` are two distinct types.

From [Type Compatibility](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Type_Compatibility_and_Identity#Type_Compatibility) you can see that none of the conditions listed indicates that the two distinct types are compatible.

> ### Type Compatibility
>
> Every type is compatible with itself. Two distinct types are compatible if they satisfy at least one of the following conditions.
>
> - They are both real types.
> - They are both integer types.
> - One type is a subrange of the other.
> - Both types are subranges of the same type.
> - Both are set types with compatible base types.
> - Both are packed-string types with the same number of characters.
> - One is a string type and the other is a string, packed-string, or Char type.
> - One type is Variant and the other is an integer, real, string, character, or Boolean type.
> - Both are class, class-reference, or interface types, and one type is derived from the other.
> - One type is PAnsiChar or PWideChar and the other is a zero-based character array of the form array[0..n] of PAnsiChar or PWideChar.
> - One type is Pointer (an untyped pointer) and the other is any pointer type.
> - Both types are (typed) pointers to the same type and the {$T+} compiler directive is in effect.
> - Both are procedural types with the same result type, the same number of parameters, and type-identity between parameters in corresponding positions.

The reason for the compiler error is thus: When you call `Tb.Create`, the compiler identifies that with `Ta.Create` and since `b` is of a distinct non-compatible type, it is not accepted.

You can call that a flaw, but it follows strict type rules and can easily be corrected like shown below.

---

Declaring `Tb = class(Ta)` would resolve the compiler error since `Tb` is derived from `Ta`.

---

Also declaring `Tb = Ta` would resolve the compiler error, since they would denote the same type (not two distinct types) and thus assignment compatible.

Comment: `> When you call Tb.Create, the compiler identifies that with Ta.Create and since b is of a distinct non-compatible type, it is not accepted.` That was new for me, but it seems the most logical explaination. Even if it feels totally wrong. When I tell the compiler, those two classes have to be treated as individuals, or "non-compatible", why this isn't mentioned when I create an object of that class? IMHO the compiler knows the classes are different and should not fall to a incompatible ancestor when `Create` is called. Or is there a good reason for it?

Comment: Pascal is a strict typed language, and two distinct class types was ruled out with regards to compatibility. It was most likely assumed that OOP ruling should be used to define how classes would interact. I agree that calling `Tb.Create` ends up in `Ta.Create` is confusing, but that is the only reference to how the class is defined.